# how to send radio button selection to server

Tags: ios, swift, radio-button

I have some text fields, and when user enter any value i will send all that to server by pressing save button. Here is that code :

```
@IBAction func addUserBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if validateProfileData() { 
        profileData.FirstName = self.data["FirstName"]!
        profileData.LastName = self.data["LastName"]!
        profileData.DateOfBirth = self.data["DateOfBirth"]!
        profileData.Email = self.data["Email"]!
        profileData.Mobile = self.data["Mobile"]!

        profileData.Country = self.data["Country"]!
        profileData.State = self.data["State"]!
        profileData.City = self.data["City"]!

        let toViewController = NextVC
    }
}
```

But I have two radio button for select the gender like male or female. I'm using this library for select the gender [Radiobutton](https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton) . But I don't know how to send that to server by pressing the save button. Please help me out..!

Comment: can you show me, the code for changing the radio button state?

Comment: Still i haven't implement. But i am using that library only.

Comment: @mack what is your problem brother 
?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya  I need to add radio button for gender male, female and i need to send to server b pressing the save button

Comment: But i am struck with the creating radio button as well as the sending which gender is selected to server

Comment: i tried with that library i have mentioned , but i was not able to create

Comment: send me project i will check it

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya  Please check your mail

Comment: @mack in your project i m not able to run in my machine so if you need some logic then i will give you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**for your male female button that i created**  you have to done country your self beacuse of i dont have time for that. i m busy in my work.

```
@IBOutlet var btn_male: UIButton! // create outlet for radio button
@IBOutlet var btn_female: UIButton! 

var gender : NSString = ""
@IBAction func btn_male_female_click(sender: UIButton) {
        switch sender.tag {
        case 10:
            //male select
            if (sender.selected == true) {
                sender.selected = false;
                btn_male.selected = true;
                btn_female.selected = false;
                gender = "1"
            }else{
                sender.selected = true;
                btn_male.selected = false;
                btn_female.selected = true;
                gender = "2"
            }
            break;
        case 20:
           //female select
            if (sender.selected == true) {
                sender.selected = false;
                btn_female.selected = true;

                btn_male.selected = false;
                gender = "2"
            }else{
                sender.selected = true;
                btn_female.selected = false;
                btn_male.selected = true;
                gender = "1"
            }

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    if profileData.Gender .isEmpty {

    }else{
        if profileData.Gender == "1"{
            self.btn_male.selected = true
        }else{
            self.btn_female.selected = true
        }

    }
}

var data:[String:String]{

     return ["FirstName":firstName.textVal,"LastName":lastName.textVal,"DateOfBirth":dateOfBirth.textVal,"Email":emailId.textVal,"Mobile":mobile.textVal,"Gender":gender as String,"Country":country.textVal,"State":state.textVal,"City":city.textVal]
}
```

in your code

```
@IBAction func addUserBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {


            profileData.FirstName = self.data["FirstName"]!
            profileData.LastName = self.data["LastName"]!
            profileData.DateOfBirth = self.data["DateOfBirth"]!
            profileData.Email = self.data["Email"]!
            profileData.Mobile = self.data["Mobile"]!

            if btn_male.selected == true {
                profileData.Gender = "1"
            }else{
                profileData.Gender = "2"
            }

            profileData.Country = self.data["Country"]!
            profileData.State = self.data["State"]!
            profileData.City = self.data["City"]!


            let toViewController = NextVC
            toViewController!.transitioningDelegate = self.transitionManager
            presentViewController(toViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

**YOUR DESIGN**

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks for your update. But how can i change the images ??

Comment: button click and set selected image into the storyboard .

Comment: I din get you. Should i need to change that image in storyboard. On using code should i need to change

Comment: from storyboard its done you dont need to do it with code now. check your mail i give there some description about this.

Comment: to server , it will send in interger type right ?.. Like if 1 means it will be male, 2 means it will be female

Comment: ya @mack its common logic brother .